# How to generate a custom image in php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, gd

I am looking to create a Product customization tool in PHP. This tool will allow the user to create his own Customization to a predefined Mobile cover. I already have a Mobile cover image and I am looking to allow a user to write 3 characters which will be written in a circle called as monogram with a background color.

I am not sure how to proceed ahead with it. I am looking to dynamically create image that is placed on the Mobile cover in such way that it looks its part.

here is a link to sample image which would be generated

http://d13eowy7ljcd3.cloudfront.net/images/ark.png

I am looking for way on how to approach it and which php image handling libraries should I make use of.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would he need to add you to skype?

Comment: What is your exact problem

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [GD and Image Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php). [imagearc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagearc.php)

There are a lot of [examples](https://techleader.pro/a/56-Basic-shapes-in-PHP-GD) out there.

You may also have a look at ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick.